# Invalid pointer address when trying to free

Tags: c, pointers

So all I'm trying to do is free a pointer and it just gives me the error 'invalid address'; though the address is clearly valid, as illustrated by the prints I put in. It tries to free the address of the pointer, but still fails. Through valgrind, it gives the error invalid free() saying the address is on thread 1's stack? The code below is runnable; can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SUCC 1
#define FAIL -1

typedef struct bucket {
   char *key;
   void *value;
   struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
   int key_count;
   int table_size;
   void (*free_value)(void *);
   Bucket **buckets;
} Table;


extern unsigned int hash_code(const char *key)  {
    unsigned int hash = 0, i = 0;
    while(i < strlen(key))  {
        hash ^= ((hash << 3) | (hash >> 29)) + key[i++];
    }
    return hash;
}

/*Makes copy of string and returns pointer to it*/
char * cpy(const char *str) {
    char *new = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    if(new)
        strcpy(new, str);
    return new;
}   


int create_table(Table ** table, int table_size, void (*free_value)(void *))    {
    *table = malloc(sizeof(Table));
    if(table && table_size != 0)    {
        int i = 0;
        (*table)->key_count = 0;   
        (*table)->table_size = table_size;
        (*table)->free_value = free_value;
        (*table)->buckets = calloc(table_size, sizeof(Bucket *));
        while(i < table_size)   
            (*table)->buckets[i++] = NULL;
        return SUCC;
    }
    return FAIL;
}


int put(Table * table, const char *key, void *value)    {
    if(table && key)    {
        int hash = hash_code(key)%table->table_size;
        Bucket *curr = table->buckets[hash];
        while(curr) {
            if(strcmp(curr->key, key) == 0)  {
                if(table->free_value)
                    table->free_value(curr->value);
                printf("addr of ptr: %p\n", value);
                curr->value = value;
                printf("addr of curr ptr: %p\n", curr->value);
                return SUCC;
            }
           curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr = malloc(sizeof(Bucket));
        curr->key = cpy(key);
        printf("addr of ptr: %p\n", value);
        curr->value = value; 
        printf("addr of curr ptr: %p\n", curr->value);
        curr->next = table->buckets[hash];
        table->buckets[hash] = curr;
        table->key_count++;

        return SUCC;
    }
    return FAIL;
}


int remove_entry(Table * table, const char *key)    {
    if(table && key)    {
        int hash = hash_code(key)%(table->table_size);
        Bucket *curr = table->buckets[hash], *prev = table->buckets[hash];
        while(curr) {
            printf("attempt");
            if(strcmp(curr->key, key) == 0)  {
                void * test = curr->value;
                printf("at addr %p\n", test);
                table->free_value(test);
                printf("freed");

                if(table->free_value){
                   table->free_value(curr->value);
                }
                free(curr->key);
                curr->key = NULL;
                curr->value = NULL;
                table->key_count--;
                if(prev == curr)
                    table->buckets[hash] = curr->next;
                else
                    prev->next = curr->next;
                free(curr);
                curr = NULL;
                return SUCC;
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    return FAIL;
}
```

And the test file that shows the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "htable.h"


int main()  {
    Table *t;
    int num2 = 3;
    printf("create: %d\n",create_table(&t, 2, free));
    printf("addr of ptr: %p\n",(void *)&num2);
    printf("put %s: %d\n","test",put(t, "test", &num2));
    printf("rem key: %d\n",remove_entry(t, "test"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to `free()` a stack variable: `num2` (in `main()`):

```
int num2 = 3;
```

Later, you have this call:

```
printf("put %s: %d\n","test",put(t, "test", &num2));
```

You're passing the address of `num2` to `put()`, which means that `remove_entry()` will try to free it later. This is illegal. You cannot free a variable allocated on the stack. You should dynamically allocate `num2` instead:

```
int* num2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
*num2 = 3;
```

There's another problem as well though. In this code:

```
void * test = curr->value;
printf("at addr %p\n", test);
table->free_value(test);
printf("freed");

if(table->free_value){
    table->free_value(curr->value);
}
```

You are freeing `curr->value` twice, because you're freeing `test` which is just a copy of the pointer.

Comment: Well that did fix that problem, but there's still something else wrong with the code because now i'm getting 'memory clobbered before allocated block' on a free() statement...thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yeah I was actually going to say that your solution didn't work when I first tried it but then I realized I hadn't taken that testing line out. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is broken:

```
char *new = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

The amount of memory you need is based on what you need to store, which is the string. You want:

```
char *new = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

Or, better yet, just use `strdup`.

Comment: Nope, still the same error. Plus, I'm getting the error on the value, not the key. But made the change nonetheless, thanks.